# Is there any way to mix(change order) rows in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I had **3 tables** which are not identical to each other. According to one of my requirement I had to copy all these tables records to another table.
That part is okay.What my problem is that the records I inserted is in a order now.
Like

```
first 100 records from table1
second 100 records from table2
third 100 records from table3
```

what I wanted to do is `change/mix` the record positions.Like if i selected first 100 records there **should** be records from **all three** table.

selecting data from `ORDER BY Rand()` is not I want.I just need to select data and display those data.
Is there any way that i can solve this out?Thanks

Comment: If you want data in a particular order, there is **one** way to guarantee that - and that's by providing an `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost `SELECT` query, when retrieving the rows.

Comment: To randomise order of a select statement, you can use the [rand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function.

Comment: When you are inserting, do you have a unique index number for each record?

Comment: Here is a post to check more solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql

Comment: @bonCodigo In my new table, I have a primary key with auto increment.I just copy data to new table without previous primary ids of other tables

Comment: @vinu check my comment to Meherzad. His query will work as long as you really don't have a condition to choose x number of rows e.g. Limit 50 rows out of 300..randomly..

Comment: Huh still i couldn't fixed this.:((

Answer (score 0):

A great post handling several cases, from simple, to gaps, to non-uniform with gaps.

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

For most general case, here's how you do it:

```
SELECT name
FROM random AS r1 JOIN
   (SELECT (RAND() *
                 (SELECT MAX(id)
                    FROM random)) AS id)
    AS r2
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

This supposes that the distribution of ids is equal, and that there can be gaps in the id list. See the article for more advanced examples

Comment: If you take a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8509/6) doesn't really seem to gurantee *fully random* but random-consecutive ;) In this case it doesn't gurantee to [give x number](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8509/6) of rows either..

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes friend i already tried this but it won't work as i expected

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to query later on with `rand()` you could create the table by inserting from a union select ordered by `rand()` in the first place:

```
INSERT INTO merged (a, b)
SELECT a, b FROM (
  SELECT a, b, rand() AS r FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a, b, rand() AS r FROM t2
) ORDER BY r
```

However, also consider this post I just came across: [INSERT INTO SELECT strange order using UNION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359652/insert-into-select-strange-order-using-union), perhaps someone can comment.

Comment: Thanks friend i got the point.Since my table are so much different from each other creating a table again with this is little bit struggle for me.I will try..